# TestCafe: testing border property of element using testcafe

Tags: css, testing, automated-tests, border, testcafe

I am trying to test the border on an image using `testcafe` using getStyleProperty('border') and it always returns undefined. Other properties like box-shadow work fine.

**HTML**:

```
<img id="imgEdit" class="img-editable" [src]="imageUrl" style="border: 12px 
solid rgb(0, 0, 0);" alt="editable image" />

const image = Selector('#imgEdit');
const imageBorder = await image.getStyleProperty('border');
```

imageBorder is always undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties#Border_Properties) in CSS is considered a [Shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties).  This is the reason why you cannot find the `border` property.

If you `console.log(image.style)`, you will see the actual `border*` CSS properties that represent the `style="border: 12px 
solid rgb(0, 0, 0);"` in your HTML.

```
  'border-bottom-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
  'border-bottom-left-radius': '0px',
  'border-bottom-right-radius': '0px',
  'border-bottom-style': 'solid',
  'border-bottom-width': '12px',
  'border-collapse': 'separate',
  'border-image-outset': '0px',
  'border-image-repeat': 'stretch',
  'border-image-slice': '100%',
  'border-image-source': 'none',
  'border-image-width': '1',
  'border-left-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
  'border-left-style': 'solid',
  'border-left-width': '12px',
  'border-right-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
  'border-right-style': 'solid',
  'border-right-width': '12px',
  'border-top-color': 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
  'border-top-left-radius': '0px',
  'border-top-right-radius': '0px',
  'border-top-style': 'solid',
  'border-top-width': '12px',
```

I am not sure which border property you want to test for, but here is a working example

`image.getStyleProperty('border-bottom-color');` outputs `rgb(0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Thanks Kin I am able to test the individual border property now.

Comment: @HarjotDhot great!  I'm glad I could help